# Differance b/w the way of hiding nav bar in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uinavigationbar

Recently i had one issue. When in my navigation controller stack (One child controller) :

```
MainScreen -> ScreenA -> ScreenB -> Screenc
```

So when in my  `Screenc` i want to hide nav bar and status bar.Its was working fine. But when i come back to my `ScreenB` my status bar and nav bar are overlap.Not sure why its happend.I search in some google and some SO answers. Then i got that `isNavigationBarHidden` base is `UIViewController` while `isHidden` base is `UIView`.

Why i hide my both nav bar and status bar with below code :

```
 override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
       self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
       self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    }
```

In my prev screen i got the issues of my status bar and nav bar are got overlapeed.

But when i use this code :

```
 override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
            return true
        }
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    }
```

Its work well. There is not overlap in my prev screen. Why its happening. Is there any specific reason behid :

`navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden`   ( vs )`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden`

I am very to the iOS Development. Just want to understand the difference. So that i can learn if i am doing any wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a huge difference. Very good point!

- The first one rudely and illegally reaches into the nav controller’s interface and manipulates it directly. You should *never* interfere with *any* other view controller's interface directly: not Cocoa's, not your own. Only a view controller should control its own interface.
- The second one politely and correctly instructs the nav controller how to behave. It is the "public API" for showing and hiding the navigation bar. — Actually the correct approach is to call `setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:)`, but setting `isNavigationBarHidden` calls that for you.

Comment: But if i follow `navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden` then only its works fine. Is that correct way to hide nav bar to avoid the status bar and nav bar to mess up ?

Comment: Why does swiping back works with `navigationBar.isHidden` and not `isNavigationBarHidden`?